# Why do I get System.IO.IOException - The response ended prematurely intermittently when I call checkout API?

Tags: adyen

Referring to this blog https://copyprogramming.com/howto/getting-httprequestexceptions-the-response-ended-prematurely
I understand that there could be two reasons- either the server we are trying to connect is blocking/rejecting the requests or I should use HTTP/2.0.

In my case I'm using the version specified for HTTP. Could you help me understand if this is an issue persistant with Adyen or is there something that can be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hey Arya, Is this behaviour consistent? Do you happen to have more information about the exact error you're getting? It's difficult to draw any conclusion based on what you are sharing now. HTTP2.0 should not be required to use the Checkout API